# Aws loadbalancers are not secure with browser even with ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

I have a domain `example.com` and I want to have https access with subdomain `my_subdomain.example.com` with aws loadbalancer

I have loadbalancer open for `443` and have route53 cname `my_subdomain.example.com` point to my loadbalancer address. I can access the site in my ec2 using browser on `my_subdomain.example.com` however its not secure in browser

My ACM has approve for both `example.com` and `*.example.com`

Is there an extra step I need for https to work, because when I do it with a single server with nginx I use https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx so I imagine I need a similar step

Can someone point me a direction?

Comment: How did you setup your https listener?

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS Certificate Manager for your certificate: it will provide a free certificate you can install on your load balancer. When you add the listener for port 443, step 3 will prompt you for a certificate, select 'Choose a certificate from ACM (recommended)'.